# Laravel DB:table created_at Date Is Different from DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, php-carbon

Running Laravel 5.6, I found this oddity:

```
> php artisan tinker

> App\Users::all();
...
created_at: "2018-06-04 16:26:00",
updated_at: "2018-06-04 16:26:00",
....
```

Pulling in the same element within a Laravel model using:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$users->first()->created_at
//2018-04-06 15:59:01
```

This is the same row.  The 35 minute delay is odd, but perhaps due to Homestead latency(?) I have no idea why the month and day are rearranged.

In my middleware, I set the locale information as such:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, env('APP_LOCALE_CODE')); //de_DE.UTF-8
date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_LOCALE_TIMEZONE')); //APP_LOCALE_TIMEZONE=Europe/Berlin
```

Anyone have an idea here?

Comment: Did your VM go to sleep? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problem-with-tinker-and-carbonnow-timestamps

Comment: I've seen 10-60 minute differences before with VMs, but switching dates around like the VM is dyslexic is odd.  These are pulled from the DB so it's strange that they are not identical.

Comment: Curious to see if something was setting the date format:
"Searching 58982 files for "Y-d-m"
0 matches across 0 files"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the query I needed required multiple joins and groupby sorting so I used DB::table instead of eloquent.  When doing so, you need to be careful of the select statement, especially with common DB fields like created_at.  Essentially it was pulling in another "created_at" field and by luck, happened to be a reverse of todays current date causing the initial thought it was a formatting error.